# В чем разница между ArrayDeque.add() и ArrayDeque.addLast()

Tags: java

Ведь оба метода добавляют элемент в конец очереди, разве нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно глянуть на исходнички (просто что загуглилось - [раз](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#L494), [два](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#l407))

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    addLast(e);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ну и намудрили...а спрашивается зачем такое делать?

Comment: выше отметили - это из за того, что структура данных должнв реализовывать разные интерфейсы. И у этих интерфейсов есть методы с разной сигнатурой, но схожим смыслом

Comment: а почему не сделать единое название add например? Или чисто из символизма мол если deque то там можно добавить в конец или начало очереди, поэтому и напишем addLast(типо по аналогии с addFirst)?

Comment: А как ты его сделаешь единым? Методы назвали так, как было удобно назвать для интерфейсов. Вот как интерфейсу подходит - так и назвали. А то, что один класс наследует 2 разных интерфейса - это проблема класса, по сути незначительная деталь реализации. В одном интерфейсе важно куда добавлять - в начало или конец, вот и назвали add first/last, а во втором ты только в конец добавляешь и другого варианта интерфейс не даёт - потому там только add и все

Comment: @sdgdrhzdrhzr у метода add возвращаемое значение boolean, а у addLast void

Answer (score 1):

по сути одно и тоже

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

метод `add()` это метод из интерфейса `Interface Collection<E>`

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а `addLast()` уже из интерфейса  `interface Deque<E>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и зачем такое нагромождение по сути одинаковых методов? Не пойму....